# What kind of MOSFET this is?

Tags: mosfet, identification

[image: MOSFET markings][image: Board with quad op amp]

What kind of a MOSFET is this / how can I tell what kind of a MOSFET this is? The markings say C3L01 8D, and searching reveals that it's made by Toshiba, but I cannot find a datasheet, and it isn't available at e.g. Digikey. I would like to figure out what kind of MOSFET it is, in order to pick a suitable replacement. It's from a late 90s era DC universal motor speed controller, the board of which is also pictured.

Comment: If you know it's a MOSFET then just chose another one with suitable specs, eg. Gate drive voltage equal or less than output of your driver circuit, voltage rating ~2x the battery voltage, current rating at least 5 times the maximum motor current.

Comment: Mains powered? Maybe a SCR?

Comment: @Kartman DC powered, 15v

Comment: @BruceAbbott how would I know whether it's P or N channel? What about depletion / enhancement? I guess I could scope out the signals the board is producing, but I don't have a scope ;)

Comment: The voltages applied tell you its polarity and type, but you can be sure that it is N-Channel because they are more powerful than p-channel, and enhancement type because depletion type need negative bias to turn off (and are quite rare in power MOSFETs). You don't need a scope to see DC voltages. Trace the circuit and understand how it works (or post it here if you can't understand it) then the required FET type will not be a mystery.